# Is built-in Animation suitable for long-running slow animations?

Tags: android, animation, performance

I need to have relatively slow moving image on home screen (some like live wallpaper) and I'm wondering, whether Android animation classes are good for that in terms of CPU load?

My concern is that android animation running constantly at the top frame rate and sometimes it produces the same X,Y coordinates several cycles in a row. And there is no way to slow down the animation frame rate.

Is there any recommendation from Google?

Answer (score 1):

Animation code is still very simple. You will not see any major slowdown, unless you are doing some really crazy amount of animations at once.

How many are you starting? If only 1, then don't worry about it, you'll be fine.

Just to give you an idea, I am starting 30+ frame animations in my game and the frame rate doesn't move much.
It would be even smoother for tweened animation IMO.